# Pandas mean function returning method datatypes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I have a large dataframe with 4 columns.

```
df
   Name Location-A Location B cart_no
   test1 56         34         3
   test2 65         31         1
   test3 16         21         2
   test4 6          14         1
df_new = df.query('cart_no == 1')

df_new["distance"]= df_new["Location-A"] - df_new["Location-B"]
avg = df_new.distance.mean()
type(avg) 
method
```

I created a new df_new as per query. On this `df_new`, there are two columns representing `location A` and `location B`, took difference between these two columns and added it to the df_new as another column.

Now when I take mean of `df_new.distance.mean` I am getting a whole series (column) as output rather than one number.

How can I find mean of the distance col in `df_new`?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't forget parentheses after `mean`? Your code in the question works fine.

Comment: yes adding parentheses works perfect